# Can't remove background from dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

I am a newbie to CSS. Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here. I am specifically concerned about the background of the dropdown menu, which it seems to inherit from the parent ul. But I want to create an output where the background is independent of the parent ul. My output comes like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xetu.png)
Whereas expected output is:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfNs0.png)
I am trying to learn creating CSS dropdowns from the w3schools website.
Code:

```css
    .navbar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropdown-button {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .navbar li:hover a,  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown-button {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: grey;
        color: orange;
        display: none;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content a {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: center;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .page-content {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.facebook.com" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.careerlauncher.com" title="Career Launcher">Career Launcher</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.cleducate.in" title="CL Educate">CL Educate</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-button" href="www.more.com" title="More...">More...</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="www.1.com" title="1">1</a>
            <a href="www.2.com" title="2">2</a>
            <a href="www.3.com" title="3">3</a>
            <a href="www.4.com" title="4">4</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not about any “background”, but about the space the elements take. If you don’t want the opened sub menu to push the rest of the page content down, then you need to position it absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take your dropdown `div` out of the document flow - use `position: absolute`

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropdown-button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li:hover a,
.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-button {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: grey;
  color: orange;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 7px #BBB;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.page-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.facebook.com" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.careerlauncher.com" title="Career Launcher">Career Launcher</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.cleducate.in" title="CL Educate">CL Educate</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-button" href="www.more.com" title="More...">More...</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="www.1.com" title="1">1</a>
      <a href="www.2.com" title="2">2</a>
      <a href="www.3.com" title="3">3</a>
      <a href="www.4.com" title="4">4</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the rationale behind the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below css for dropdown menu:

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uacud4e0/)

CSS:

```
.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #c5c5c5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content {
z-index: 1;
background-color: grey;
color: orange;
display: none;
width: 200px;
}
```

To this add `position: absolute` and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute in .dropdown-content and position relative in .dropdown. Below is the css.

```
.navbar .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: grey;
    color: orange;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
}
```